# Add each value from each iterations from a for loop c#

Tags: c#

I want to add each A value of each iteration together. In this loop it will go around ten times, so i will have 10 different A values. I want the total value of every A. I have solved it, but i feel like its must be an easier way to do it. So my question is, is there an easier way to do it?

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int e = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{                
     a = i * i;
     c = a + b;
     c = e + c;
     e = c;                
}
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Tried `a += i*i` ?

Comment: What's the point of `b` it's always just 0?

Comment: How have you solved it? You are always overwriting `a`, in what way this is the _"total value of a"_?

Comment: @Jdoe do you know how to use the debugger..? also do you know how to code review your own code..? you know basic mathematics ?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. After the loop, what value do you want to see in `c` variable?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I want to see the value of 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + 10^2 = 385.

Comment: @MethodMan No i do not know how to use the debugger and no i would not say that i can code review my own code. Yes i hope and think i know some basic mathematics.

Comment: how can you write code and not know how to use the debugger..? well take some time and read up on how to do that..

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ:

```
int a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Sum(i => i * i);
```

Which is the same as:

```
int a = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    a += i * i;
}
```

By the way, if you want to calculate any power of `i` use `Math.Pow`:

```
int a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Sum(i => (int)Math.Pow(i, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, with this i dont even have to use a loop and i did not know about the Math.Pow thing.

Comment: @J.doe: just to clarify: LINQ also uses loops, you just don't see them. So use LINQ because it can help to simplify your code(what is important) but don't expect it to run faster.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but how can does `.Sum(i => i * i);` work if i never  declare the i variable?

Comment: @J.doe: it's a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and passed as parameter to the `Enumerable.Sum` method because the input sequnce was `IEnumerable<int>`(came from `Enumerable.Range`). The [`Enumerable`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) contains a lot of generic extension methods(used for LINQ queries). The input sequence determines the type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't really make sense. For example, why are you assigning a value to `c`, but then assigning another value in the next line? The result is that the first value is not used.

But to answer your question specifically to *"I want the total value of every A.*".

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int e = 0;
int total = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{                
    a = i * i;
    c = a + b;
    c = e + c;
    e = c;              
    total += a;  
}
Console.WriteLine(total);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Its summing the squares of 1 to 10, just in a really convoluted way.

Comment: Thanks, i cant really say why. But it had to be there for it to work.

Comment: @J.doe Well I guess you took a wrong turn and then shot yourself through the back into the foot: b is always 0. So c = a +b is always a, then c is set to e + c which is value from last iteration + a , the e is updated to that value. Which can be shortened to a = a + i * i which is a+= i * i.